# How to pair with bluetooth speaker using USB bluetooth dongle?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I've attached a bluetooth dongle to my Win-7 Laptop. It showed up in my devices group, but now how do I pair it to my bluetooth speakers and play music from either a media player program, and more importantly an online media player (such as NPR's)?

Answer (score 2):

It would have been helpful if you provided more info such as the USB Bluetooth device you are using.
You may possibly need to install additional drivers and software however this tutorial should help you out http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/add-a-bluetooth-enabled-device-to-your-computer

Comment: The USB dongle is a CSR BlueCore Bluetooth dongle, and the speaker I want to pair is an ATIVA DS-1168.

Comment: In that case this tutorial will help you: http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2343157/connect-bluetooth-speakers-windows-laptop.html

Comment: The info didn't help. I do all the steps recommended but the bluetooth speaker doesn't show up in the available devices window. and yes I have turned on the speaker's discoverable mode.

Comment: @DavidL. Both tutorials (Windows Support and Tom's Guide) say almost the same thing, except the Windows Support article omits the step 1 on Tom's Guide. That's the most important part. Please make sure you are doing it.